# Testing Windows' implementation of Python multiprocessing on Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, multiprocessing

CPython's `multiprocessing` package is implemented fairly differently on Windows and on Linux, as a Windows implementation cannot rely on `fork(2)`.  However, it seems to me that the Windows implementation of `multiprocessing` (spawning a separate process and send it the required state by serializing it) should work on Linux (or am I wrong?).

While I work on Linux, I would like to make sure that the code I write also works on Windows (e.g., not accidentally have unpicklable arguments, etc.).  Is there a way I can force CPython to use the Windows implementation of `multiprocessing` on Linux?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so. As you notice, the process model of Linux and of Windows are profoundly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum, in fact this has just become possible very recently: http://bugs.python.org/issue8713.
Now I just have to run 3.4alpha2 :)